# Does getBatchItem method of AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient object supports Global Secondary Index?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient in a nodejs program to fetch items from multiple Dynamodb tables. To make code simple, I choose to use BatchGetItem/BatchGet method.

The challenge is I need to fetch items based on a **Global Secondary Index**, e.g. name+age, rather than the initial primary key generated when creating the table.  I went through [BatchGetItem/BatchGet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) but not see any parameters of using Global Secondary Index.

I ran some testing with the following code

> ```
> var params = {
>   RequestItems: {
>     'Table-1': {
>       Keys: [
>         { 
>             name: 'abc',
>             age: 18,
>          },
>       ]
>     }
>   }
> };
>
> var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
>
> docClient.batchGet(params, function(err, data) {
>   if (err) console.log(err);
>   else console.log(data);
> });
> ```

And got following error.

```
> ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the
> schema
```

Does it mean BatchGetItem/BatchGet can't use Global Secondary Index, and I have to read from tables one by one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. You will likely have to query one-by-one.

> INDEXES - The response includes the aggregate ConsumedCapacity for the operation, together with ConsumedCapacity for each table and secondary index that was accessed. **Note that some operations, such as GetItem and BatchGetItem , do not access any indexes at all.** In these cases, specifying INDEXES will only return ConsumedCapacity information for table(s).

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/batch-get-item.html